# Stroke animation, how to attach another path to the appearing stroke?

Tags: html, css, animation, svg

I have the following animation:

```css
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dashoffset: 0;
  }
}

#currency-chart-path {
  stroke-dasharray: 1000;
  stroke-dashoffset: 1000;
  animation: dash 30s linear forwards;
}
```

```html
<svg id="city-total-v2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="0 0 1000 1000" enable-background="new 0 0 1000 1000" xml:space="preserve">
<g id="Chartline">
  <path id="currency-chart-path" stroke="#7C0A67" stroke-width="3px" fill="none" d="M443,439 L464,435 487,421 511,416 532,424 552,408 572,414 591,413 606,419" />
 <path id="chart-arrow" fill="#7C0A67" d="M604.4,423.5l6.88-2.26l-2.44-3.3c-0.1-0.22-0.25-0.41-0.43-0.58l0.01,0.02l-0.02-0.02
  c0,0,0,0.01,0.01,0.01l-2.48-3.36l-0.08,0.42l-0.27,1.66l-0.03-0.01l-0.68,3.8l0.09,0.04L604.4,423.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

**Run the code snippet** to see the animation.

I want to attach the arrow to the stroke so it look like following the path.

How is that possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible, however in this case you will need JavaScript. Please reed the comments in my code.

```js
let chart = document.querySelector("#currency_chart_path");
// the length of the chart path
let length = currency_chart_path.getTotalLength();
// the request animation id
let rid = null;
// setting the stroke-dasharray and the stroke-dashoffset for the chart
chart.style.strokeDasharray = length;
chart.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
// the animation frames
let frames = length;
// two points on the path: the actual point and an other point very near used to calculate the angle of rotation for the arrow
let point1, point2;
// the animation:
function Frame() {
  rid = requestAnimationFrame(Frame);
  chart.style.strokeDashoffset = frames;
  //two points on the path: the actual point and an other point very near
  point1 = chart.getPointAtLength(length - frames);
  point2 = chart.getPointAtLength((length - frames + 2) % length);
  //the angle of rotation for the arrow
  angle = Math.atan2(point2.y - point1.y, point2.x - point1.x);
  // set the transformation for the arrow
  arrow.setAttribute(
    "transform",
    "translate(" +
      [point1.x, point1.y] +
      ")" +
      "rotate(" +
      angle * 180 / Math.PI +
      ")"
  );

  frames--;
  // stop the animation
  if (frames <= 2) {
    cancelAnimationFrame(rid);
    rid = null;
  }
}

Frame();
```

```css
svg{border:1px solid}
```

```html
<svg id="city-total-v2" viewBox="400 370 250 100" >
<g id="Chartline">
<path id="currency_chart_path" stroke="#7C0A67" stroke-width="3px" fill="none" d="M443,439 L464,435 487,421 511,416 532,424 552,408 572,414 591,413 606,419" />
<path id="arrow" fill="#7C0A67" d="M0,0L0,-5L7,0L0,5"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

This is inspired by a demo in [Using SVG with CSS3 and HTML5: Vector Graphics for Web Design](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/1491921978)

Comment: The `arrow` id the arrow that follows the `chart` path. I couldn't use the one in your code since it wasn't appropriate. When you do this sort of things you need to draw the arrow (in this case) in the origin of svg canvas.

Comment: Hi, Thanks this is exactly what I needed. Is there a way I can play with the animation duration ?

Comment: I've tried to increase the `frame` but that didn't work well

Comment: Insetad of reducing `frames` by one each step (`frames--`), try reducing it by less than 1. For instance, subtracting 0.5 instead (`frames -= 0.5;`) will double the length of the animation.

Answer (score 4):

An idea is to run the animation in the opposite direction while doing a translation

```css
@keyframes dash {
  to {
    stroke-dasharray: 190;
  }
}

@keyframes move {
  to {
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
}

#currency-chart-path {
  stroke-dasharray: 279;
  stroke-dashoffset: 381;
  animation: dash 10s linear forwards;
}

#Chartline {
  animation: move 10s linear forwards;
  transform: translateX(-200px);
}
```

```html
<svg id="city-total-v2" version="1.1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px" viewBox="300 300 400 400">
<g id="Chartline">
  <path id="currency-chart-path" stroke="#7C0A67" stroke-width="3px" fill="none" d="M443,439 L464,435 487,421 511,416 532,424 552,408 572,414 591,413 606,419" />
 <path id="chart-arrow" fill="#7C0A67" d="M604.4,423.5l6.88-2.26l-2.44-3.3c-0.1-0.22-0.25-0.41-0.43-0.58l0.01,0.02l-0.02-0.02
  c0,0,0,0.01,0.01,0.01l-2.48-3.36l-0.08,0.42l-0.27,1.66l-0.03-0.01l-0.68,3.8l0.09,0.04L604.4,423.5z"/>
</g>
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks, that's interesting, I will go with @enxaneta solution as it is closer to what I want.

Answer (score 3):

### Pure SVG Smil solution

You can use stroke-dashoffset to animate line growth.
A marker is used as an arrow at the end of the line, but it cannot be made to move with the line, since the line does not actually grow.

The line is drawn in advance and its growth is simply animated by decreasing the stroke-dashoffset from 177px to zero.

You can use another technique: add an animation of the movement of an arrow along this line to the animation of the growth of the line. It is necessary to set the same time for both animations and therefore the desired effect will be created:

```html
<svg id="city-total-v2" viewBox="400 370 250 100" style="border:1px solid;" >
<g id="Chartline">
<path id="currency_chart_path" stroke-dasharray="177" stroke="#7C0A67" stroke-width="3px" fill="none" d="M443,439 L464,435 487,421 511,416 532,424 552,408 572,414 591,413 606,419" >
  <!-- Line growth animation -->
<animate
 attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
 begin="0s"
 dur="4s"
 values="177;0"
 repeatCount="indefinite" />
</path>
<path id="arrow" transform="rotate(180)" fill="#7C0A67" d="M0,0L0,-5L7,0L0,5">
  <!-- Animate an arrow along a line   -->
 <animateMotion
   id="an"
   dur="4s"
   repeatCount="indefinite"
   rotate="auto-reverse"
   begin="0s"
   restart="whenNotActive">
       <mpath xlink:href="#currency_chart_path"/>
</animateMotion>
</path>
</g> 
</svg>
```

Option with additional chart elements

*The animation will start after clicking*

```html
<svg id="city_total_v2" viewBox="400 370 250 100" style="border:1px solid;" >
    <defs>
  <marker id="mark" markerWidth="6.5" markerHeight="8" refX="5.5" refY="1"
           orient="45">
        
        <polygon points="0,3.25 3.25,6.5 6.5,0" fill="black" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="black" />
  </marker> 
  <marker id="mark2" markerWidth="7" markerHeight="7" refX="3.5" refY="3"
           orient="-45">
        
        <polygon points="0,3.25 3.25,6.5 6.5,0" fill="black" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="black" />
  </marker>
</defs>   
    <g transform="translate(440 465)">
     <polyline  points="0,0 190,0" marker-end ="url(#mark)" fill="none" stroke="black" />
      <polyline  points="0,0 0,-85" marker-end ="url(#mark2)" fill="none" stroke="black" /> 
       <rect x="3" y="-24" width="19" height="23" fill="red" />
       <rect x="28" y="-30" width="19" height="29" fill="crimson" />
        <rect x="53" y="-43" width="19" height="42" fill="gold" /> 
         <rect x="78" y="-38" width="19" height="37" fill="orange" />
         <rect x="103" y="-52" width="19" height="51" fill="skyblue" /> 
          <rect x="128" y="-48" width="19" height="47" fill="yellowgreen" /> 
          <rect x="153" y="-41" width="19" height="40" fill="orange" />
   </g>
<g id="Chartline">
<path id="currency_chart_path" stroke-dasharray="177" stroke-dashoffset="177" stroke="#7C0A67" stroke-width="3px" fill="none" d="M443,439 L464,435 487,421 511,416 532,424 552,408 572,414 591,413 606,419" >
   <!--Line growth animation -->
<animate
  attributeName="stroke-dashoffset"
  begin="city_total_v2.click"
  dur="7s"
  values="177;0"
  fill="freeze"
  restart="whenNotActive" />
</path>
<path id="arrow" transform="rotate(180)" fill="#7C0A67" d="M0,0L0,-5L7,0L0,5">
  <!--Arrow movement animation -->
  <animateMotion 
   id="an"
   dur="7s"
   repeatCount="1"
   rotate="auto-reverse"
   begin="city_total_v2.click"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive">
       <mpath xlink:href="#currency_chart_path"/>
</animateMotion>
</path>
</g> 
</svg>
```

*Added rectangle animations to arrow animation*

```html
<svg id="city_total_v2" viewBox="400 370 250 100" style="border:1px solid;" >
<defs>
  <marker id="mark" markerWidth="6.5" markerHeight="8" refX="5.5" refY="1" orient="45">        
        <polygon points="0,3.25 3.25,6.5 6.5,0" fill="black" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="black" />
  </marker> 
  <marker id="mark2" markerWidth="7" markerHeight="7" refX="3.5" refY="3"   orient="-45">        
        <polygon points="0,3.25 3.25,6.5 6.5,0" fill="black" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="black" />
  </marker>
</defs>   
   <g transform="translate(440 465)">
         <rect x="3" y="0" width="19" height="23" fill="red" >
            <!-- Animating the first rectangle -->
          <animate id="an1" attributeName="y" begin="city_total_v2.click" dur="1s" values="-1;-24" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
       </rect>
      
       <rect x="28" y="0" width="19" height="29" fill="crimson" >
           <!-- Animating the second rectangle -->
         <animate id="an2" attributeName="y" begin="an1.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-30" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
       </rect>
        <rect x="53" y="0" width="19" height="42" fill="gold" >
           <animate id="an3" attributeName="y" begin="an2.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-43" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
       </rect>          
         <rect x="78" y="0" width="19" height="37" fill="orange" >
            <animate id="an4" attributeName="y" begin="an3.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-37" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
         </rect>        
           <rect x="103" y="0" width="19" height="51" fill="skyblue" >
             <animate id="an5" attributeName="y" begin="an4.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-52" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
           </rect>       
          <rect x="128" y="0" width="19" height="47" fill="yellowgreen" >
              <animate id="an6" attributeName="y" begin="an5.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-48" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
          </rect>    
          <rect x="153" y="0" width="19" height="40" fill="orange" >
             <animate id="an7" attributeName="y" begin="an6.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-41" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
       </rect>                
              <!-- masking strip          -->
         <rect x="1" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
        <polyline  marker-end ="url(#mark)" points="0,0 200,0" fill="none" stroke="black" />
      <polyline  marker-end ="url(#mark2)" points="0,0 0,-85" fill="none" stroke="black" />   
   </g>
<g id="Chartline">
<path id="currency_chart_path" stroke-dasharray="177" stroke-dashoffset="177" stroke="#7C0A67" stroke-width="3px" fill="none" d="M443,439 L464,435 487,421 511,416 532,424 552,408 572,414 591,413 606,419" >
   <!-- Line animation -->
<animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="city_total_v2.click" dur="7s" values="177;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
</path>
<path id="arrow" transform="rotate(180)" fill="#7C0A67" d="M0,0L0,-5L7,0L0,5">
    <!-- Arrow animation -->
  <animateMotion
   id="an"
   dur="7s"
   repeatCount="1"
   rotate="auto-reverse"
   begin="city_total_v2.click"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive">
       <mpath xlink:href="#currency_chart_path"/>
</animateMotion>
</path>
</g> 
</svg>
```

*Chart animation loop*

```html
<svg id="city_total_v2" viewBox="400 370 250 100" style="border:1px solid;" >
<defs>
  <marker id="mark" markerWidth="6.5" markerHeight="8" refX="5.5" refY="1" orient="45">        
        <polygon points="0,3.25 3.25,6.5 6.5,0" fill="black" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="black" />
  </marker> 
  <marker id="mark2" markerWidth="7" markerHeight="7" refX="3.5" refY="3"  orient="-45">        
        <polygon points="0,3.25 3.25,6.5 6.5,0" fill="black" stroke-width="0.25" stroke="black" />
  </marker>
</defs>   
   <g transform="translate(440 465)">
      <rect x="3" y="0" width="19" height="23" fill="red" >
          <animate id="an1" attributeName="y" begin="city_total_v2.click;an7.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-24" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
       </rect>
      
       <rect x="28" y="0" width="19" height="29" fill="crimson" >
         <animate id="an2" attributeName="y" begin="an1.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-30" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
       </rect>
        <rect x="53" y="0" width="19" height="42" fill="gold" >
           <animate id="an3" attributeName="y" begin="an2.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-43" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
       </rect>          
         <rect x="78" y="0" width="19" height="37" fill="orange" >
            <animate id="an4" attributeName="y" begin="an3.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-37" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
         </rect>        
           <rect x="103" y="0" width="19" height="51" fill="skyblue" >
             <animate id="an5" attributeName="y" begin="an4.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-52" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
           </rect>       
          <rect x="128" y="0" width="19" height="47" fill="yellowgreen" >
              <animate id="an6" attributeName="y" begin="an5.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-48" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
          </rect>    
          <rect x="153" y="0" width="19" height="40" fill="orange" >
             <animate id="an7" attributeName="y" begin="an6.end" dur="1s" values="-1;-41" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
       </rect>                
              <!-- masking strip          -->
         <rect x="1" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" fill="white" />
        <polyline  marker-end ="url(#mark)" points="0,0 200,0" fill="none" stroke="black" />
      <polyline  marker-end ="url(#mark2)" points="0,0 0,-85" fill="none" stroke="black" />   
   </g>
<g id="Chartline">
<path id="currency_chart_path" stroke-dasharray="177" stroke-dashoffset="177" stroke="#7C0A67" stroke-width="3px" fill="none" d="M443,439 L464,435 487,421 511,416 532,424 552,408 572,414 591,413 606,419" >
   <!-- Line animation -->
<animate attributeName="stroke-dashoffset" begin="city_total_v2.click;an7.end" dur="7s" values="177;0" fill="freeze" restart="whenNotActive" />
</path>
<path id="arrow" transform="rotate(180)" fill="#7C0A67" d="M0,0L0,-5L7,0L0,5">
    <!-- Arrow animation -->
  <animateMotion
   id="an"
   dur="7s"
   repeatCount="1"
   rotate="auto-reverse"
   begin="city_total_v2.click;an7.end"
   fill="freeze"
   restart="whenNotActive">
       <mpath xlink:href="#currency_chart_path"/>
</animateMotion>
</path>
</g> 
</svg>
```