# Move to Mouse Click in SVG path (d3.js)

Tags: javascript, html, d3.js, svg

I need to create a circle and move it to the closest point in an SVG path on mousedown event

[here is the jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2uawozcn/)

The Code:

```
        var points = [[180,300],[234,335],[288,310],[350,290],[405,300],[430,305],[475,310],[513,300],[550,280]];

        var width = 1000, height = 600;
        var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("cardinal");
        var svg = d3.select("#Con").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
        var path = svg.append("path").datum(points).attr("d", line);
        var line = svg.append("line");
        var circle = svg.append("   circle").attr("cx", -10).attr("cy", -10).attr("r", 3.5);
        svg.append("rect").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).on("mousedown", mouseclick);
        function mouseclick() {
            var m = d3.mouse(this),p = closestPoint(path.node(), m);
            circle.attr("cx", p[0]).attr("cy", p[1]);
        }
        function closestPoint(pathNode, point) {
            var pathLength = pathNode.getTotalLength(),precision = 8,best,bestLength,bestDistance = Infinity;
            for (var scan, scanLength = 0, scanDistance; scanLength <= pathLength; scanLength += precision) {
                if ((scanDistance = distance2(scan = pathNode.getPointAtLength(scanLength))) < bestDistance) {
                    best = scan, bestLength = scanLength, bestDistance = scanDistance;
                }
            }
            precision /= 2;
            while (precision > 0.5) {
                var before,after,beforeLength,afterLength,beforeDistance,afterDistance;
                if ((beforeLength = bestLength - precision) >= 0 && (beforeDistance = distance2(before = pathNode.getPointAtLength(beforeLength))) < bestDistance) {
                    best = before, bestLength = beforeLength, bestDistance = beforeDistance;
                } else if ((afterLength = bestLength + precision) <= pathLength && (afterDistance = distance2(after = pathNode.getPointAtLength(afterLength))) < bestDistance) {
                    best = after, bestLength = afterLength, bestDistance = afterDistance;
                } else {
                    precision /= 2;
                }
            }
            best = [best.x, best.y];
            best.distance = Math.sqrt(bestDistance);
            return best;
            function distance2(p) {
                var dx = p.x - point[0],dy = p.y - point[1];
                return dx * dx + dy * dy;
            }
        }
```

I need to move the circle to the closest point in the path when I click in the SVG space

In my code the circle moves without animation and I need to animate it so that it moves on the path from point to point

I need it to always move with one speed whether it moves a large or small distance

like this:

https://a.top4top.net/p_11885szd41.gif

Comment: This seems to be close to  a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/54523405/1978785 Does this question cover what you are asking? If not can you edit your question to be more specific?

Comment: From your jsfiddle it looks like you are not having trouble with the mouse down event. Is it just animation that you need help with? This stroke animation question also seems to be very close to what you are asking. Does this question help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53738351/stroke-animation-how-to-attach-another-path-to-the-appearing-stroke

Comment: In the both questions the path is changing(animating), I don't want the path change, I want to animate the circle movement.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. You have a couple of nice answers now. Up vote all the answers that are helpful and eventually accept the answer that you think best answers your questions. If none of the answers are sufficient to answer your question you can edit your question to make it more clear what you are asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This answer modifies your code to move a circle from the start of the line or from the last mouse click to the current mouse click. It animates the movement of the circle by calling an animate method with `setTimeout` until the circle has moved from the beginning of the line to the point where the mouse was clicked.

The interesting code is here:

```
        // getAnimate returns a function that is within a closure
       function getAnimate(pLength, path, currentIndex, finishPos, forward){
              let animate = function (){
                let scan = path.node().getPointAtLength(currentIndex);
                if (scan.x < finishPos || !forward && scan.x > finishPos){
                  circle.attr("cx", scan.x).attr("cy", scan.y);
                }
              if (forward){
                currentIndex += 1;
                lastIndex = currentIndex;
                if (scan.x < finishPos){
                  setTimeout(animate, 50);
                  }
                } else {
                    currentIndex -= 1;
                    lastIndex = currentIndex;
                if (scan.x > finishPos){
                  setTimeout(animate, 50);
                }
              }
            }
             return animate;
           }
```

```js
    var points = [[80,100],[134,115],[188,130],[250,120],[305,120],[330,101],[375,103],[413,100],[550,90]];
                var width = 500, height = 200;
                var line = d3.svg.line().interpolate("cardinal");
                var svg = d3.select("#Con").append("svg").attr("width", width).attr("height", height);
                var path = svg.append("path").datum(points).attr("d", line);
                var line = svg.append("line");
                var circle = svg.append("circle").attr("cx", -10).attr("cy", -10).attr("r", 3.5);
                svg.append("rect").attr("width", width).attr("height", height).on("mousedown", mouseclick);
                var lastIndex = 0;
                function mouseclick() {
                  let m = d3.mouse(this);
                  let p = closestPoint(path.node(), m);
                  let forward = true;
                  let currentPoint = path.node().getPointAtLength(lastIndex);                  
                   if (p[0] < currentPoint.x){
                     forward = false;
                   }
                  let pathLength = path.node().getTotalLength();
                  getAnimate(pathLength, path, lastIndex, p[0], forward)();
                }

                function getAnimate(pLength, path, currentIndex, finishPos, forward){
                  let animate = function (){
                    let scan = path.node().getPointAtLength(currentIndex);
                    if (scan.x < finishPos || !forward && scan.x > finishPos){
                      circle.attr("cx", scan.x).attr("cy", scan.y);
                    }
                  if (forward){
                  currentIndex += 1;
                  lastIndex = currentIndex;
                  if (scan.x < finishPos){
                    setTimeout(animate, 50);
                    }
                    } else {
                          currentIndex -= 1;
                          lastIndex = currentIndex;
                  if (scan.x > finishPos){
                    setTimeout(animate, 50);
                    }
                    }
                }
                 return animate;
               }

                function closestPoint(pathNode, point) {
                    var pathLength = pathNode.getTotalLength(),precision = 8,best,bestLength,bestDistance = Infinity;
                    for (var scan, scanLength = 0, scanDistance; scanLength <= pathLength; scanLength += precision) {
                        if ((scanDistance = distance2(scan = pathNode.getPointAtLength(scanLength))) < bestDistance) {
                            best = scan, bestLength = scanLength, bestDistance = scanDistance;
                        }
                    }
                    precision /= 2;
                    while (precision > 0.5) {
                        var before,after,beforeLength,afterLength,beforeDistance,afterDistance;
                        if ((beforeLength = bestLength - precision) >= 0 && (beforeDistance = distance2(before = pathNode.getPointAtLength(beforeLength))) < bestDistance) {
                            best = before, bestLength = beforeLength, bestDistance = beforeDistance;
                        } else if ((afterLength = bestLength + precision) <= pathLength && (afterDistance = distance2(after = pathNode.getPointAtLength(afterLength))) < bestDistance) {
                            best = after, bestLength = afterLength, bestDistance = afterDistance;
                        } else {
                            precision /= 2;
                        }
                    }
                    best = [best.x, best.y];
                    best.distance = Math.sqrt(bestDistance);
                    return best;
                    function distance2(p) {
                        var dx = p.x - point[0],dy = p.y - point[1];
                        return dx * dx + dy * dy;
                    }
                }
```

```css
    * {
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }
    #Con {
        border: 1px solid black;
        margin: auto;
        width: 1000px;
        height: 600px;
    }
    #Map{
        z-index: -1000;
        position: absolute;
    }
    #Cha {
        position: absolute;
    }
    path {
        z-index: 1000;
        fill: none;
        stroke: #000;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    line {
        fill: none;
        stroke: red;
        stroke-width: 1.5px;
    }
    circle {
      fill: red;
    }
    rect {
        fill: none;
        pointer-events: all;
    }
```

```html
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://mbostock.github.com/d3/d3.js?2.5.0"></script>

     <div id="Con"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for answering my question, this is so close to what I want, but I need the circle moves from it's current position (not from the beginning of the path).

Comment: I updated so that the code keeps track of the last mouse click and determines a direction so that the animation can move the red circle from the previous mouse click to the current mouse click.

Comment: If you have an additional question post it as a new question.

Answer (score 3):

I'm not using your code but I hope you'll get the idea.

Instead of using a circle I'm using the track:

```
<use id="theUse" xlink:href="#track"
```

This track has a `stroke-dasharray` of `".1 398.80"` This means a dash of `.1` (very very small) and a gap of `398.80` as long as the track. The `stroke-width` is 7 with `stroke-linecap= "round"`and this is transforming the dash into a circle. I'm changing the position of the dash (the circle) using `stroke-dashoffset` and in order to animate the change I'm using `transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s;`in the css.

I hope it helps.

```js
let m;
let L = track.getTotalLength();
let _start = {x:180,y:30}
let _end = {x:550,y:280}
let l = dist(_start, _end);
theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-dashoffset",L);

svg.addEventListener("click",(e)=>{
  m = oMousePosSVG(e)
  
  let pos = m.x - _start.x;
  let theDistance = map(pos,_start.x,_end.x,0,L)
  let s_dof = constrain(L-theDistance, .5, L-.5)
  
  theUse.setAttributeNS(null,"stroke-dashoffset",s_dof)  
})

function oMousePosSVG(e) {
      var p = svg.createSVGPoint();
      p.x = e.clientX;
      p.y = e.clientY;
      var ctm = svg.getScreenCTM().inverse();
      var p =  p.matrixTransform(ctm);
      return p;
}

function dist(p1, p2) {
  let dx = p2.x - p1.x;
  let dy = p2.y - p1.y;
  return Math.sqrt(dx * dx + dy * dy);
}

function map(n, a, b, _a, _b) {
  let d = b - a;
  let _d = _b - _a;
  let u = _d / d;
  return _a + n * u;
}

function constrain(n, low, high) {
  return Math.max(Math.min(n, high), low);
};
```

```css
svg {
  border: 1px solid;
}
path {
  fill: none;
}

#theUse {
 
  transition: stroke-dashoffset 1s;
  
}
```

```html
<svg id="svg" viewBox="150 250 450 100">
  <defs>
<path id="track" d="M180,300Q223.2,334,234,335C250.2,336.5,270.6,316.75,288,310S332.45,291.5,350,290S393,297.75,405,300S419.5,303.5,430,305S462.55,310.75,475,310S501.75,304.5,513,300Q520.5,297,550,280"></path>
  </defs> 
  <use  xlink:href="#track" stroke="black" />
  <use id="theUse" xlink:href="#track" stroke-width="7" stroke-dasharray = ".1 398.80" stroke="red" stroke-linecap= "round" />
  
 
</svg>
```

Comment: Thanks for this helpful answer, the only problem in this is the transition is when I click to very close to the circle it's move slow and when I click to far away to it it's move fast